# Building ionic cordova with Android devices

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

Hello I am getting this error whenever I'm trying to run ionic cordova run android. I have set my environment variables for ANDROID_HOME and also for SDK_ROOT Moreover I have jdk 8 installed. Any help would be appreciated thank you.[image: Snippet of compiler]

Comment: can you remove android platform and add it again, and try

Comment: Not working still throwing same error